# Deleted chat - can it still have a back up on google drive

Tags: backup

If I delete my chats on WhatsApp as soon as it is over(Within an hour). Will google drive still have it backed up?

Comment: If you backup it they will be on google, but if you overwrite backup with one without that chat, than probably you won't be able to restoe that chat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the option to backup is selected, WhatsApp does this at 2am (0200). You can see this in the Settings > Chat > Chat Backup menu. I would guess that chats that do not exists at that point are not backed up, i.e. if a chat exists in its entirety and is deleted before 2am, there is nothing to back up.